# Unable to connect to IBM MQ from C# console application with credentials

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am unable to connect to IBM MQ from C# console application with credentials. Here is the code. Its throwing "2035 Not Authorized" error.

```
protected MQQueueManager mqQueueManager;
public override void Open() {
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, mq_hostName);
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, mq_channel);
properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, mq_port);
properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, mq_userName);
properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, mq_password);
properties.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);

try
{
mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(mq_queueManagerName, properties);
Console.WriteLine("Connected to MQ");
}

catch (MQException e)
{
log.Fatal("MQ Queue Manager creation Error", e);
throw e;
}
}
```

What I have tried:

If I comment user name and password properties. It’s able to connect. Not sure, why it’s not working with credentials. Please let me know if anyone has encountered this issue and any pointers to resolve the same.

Comment: Please review the queue manager error logs, this will show you a more specific error that will indicate the cause of the 2035 error.   The 2035 could be caused by many things.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with user name. We are migrating Java application to .NET and in user name "**@domain**" was there at the end. Looks like, this format is required for Java and its working fine there. When we use same user name in .NET, it was not working and throwing error "2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED". Once we removed @domain from it, it started working.

Comment: Hello Srini, I don't have any @domain name in the user id, but it's still failing to connect to MQ, any thoughts?